# aborting jython script from java

Tags: java, python, multithreading, abort

I'm using jython in the following way for starting a python script from java:

```
final PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.execfile(scriptFile);
```

This happens usually in a new thread.

Is there any way to kill the script interpreter from "the outside", i.e. from java (this would for example be needed if the script is caught in an endless loop)? The Thread.stop() method is deprecated, so I can't use this. I also cannot query a boolean variable regularily as it is commonly done when someone ones to make another thread abort, because I cannot modify the jython code.

Comment: did you try interp.set()? It might be able to change a variable that way...

Other than that, put that endless loop outside the python script?

Comment: @DThought unfortunately, the python scripts do some blocking I/O actions (http etc.), which cannot be aborted by setting a variable as you said. Moreover, in the scripts I would have to query the variable after each command.